# Transformation to normality when data is trimmed at a specific value

Tags: normal-distribution, normalization

So let's say I have an original dataset $x\sim N(58, 3.5)$, but then I go and take only the records with $x \geq 54$ and continue working with this trimmed data.

Now, as I understand, this trimmed data set is not normally distributed since I have cut a big chunk of data and I can't apply statistical methods relevant for normally distributed data?

I assume, in this case I'll need to transform the dataset to normal, but I'm not exactly sure how to do it in this particular case. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you could first explain which methods requiring normality you intend to apply?

Comment: Why transform it to normality?

Comment: @kurtosis, for example, if I wanted to use the distribution of this new dataset and some calculations using standard deviation then the original std of 3.5 shouldn't be applicable since it's not the same data?

Comment: OK, but determining the standard deviation does not require normality. I'm asking because many people think methods require normality when they do not.

Comment: If all you want is the standard deviation of a truncated normal distribution, there are formulas for that. What kind of calculations using SD do you have in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't want to use t methods to make confidence intervals or test
hypotheses based on samples of $n=20$ truncated observations.

- The first histogram below shows the a histogram along with a density curve of the (skewed) truncated normal distribution.
- The second histogram is for means of 20 truncated values;
  it seems roughly normal, but means do fail a Shapiro-Wilk normality test.
- However, the scatterplot shows that means and standard deviations
  of truncated samples of $n=20$ are not independent (correlation $r \approx 0.37),$
  so that "t-ratios" cannot have Student's t distributions. [For normal data, $\bar X$ and $S$ are independent random variables.]

.

```
set.seed(725)
q = pnorm(54, 58, 3.5); q
[1] 0.126549
x = qnorm(runif(20*10^5, q, 1), 58, 3.5)
MAT = matrix(x, nrow=10^5, ncol=20)
a = rowMeans(MAT)
shapiro.test(a[1:5000])$p.val
[1] 2.480093e-05
s = apply(MAT, 1, sd)
mean(s)
[1] 2.833662
cor(a, s)
[1] 0.3752128
t = (a - mean(a))*sqrt(20)/s; ks.test(t, pt, 19)$p.val
[1] 0            # 't.stat' not Student's t distributed
qt(.975, 19)
[1] 2.093024
mean(t < -2.093); mean(t > 2.093)
[1] 0.03545      # tails 'unbalanced'
[1] 0.01703

par(mfrow=c(1,3))
 hist(x, prob=T, col="skyblue2", main="Truncated Normal")
  curve(dnorm(x, 58, 3.5)/(1-q), add=T, col="red")
 hist(a, prob=T, br=30, col="skyblue2", main="Means of 20")
  curve(dnorm(x, mean(a), sd(a)), add=T, col="red")
 plot(a, s, pch=".")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

Comment: The Student confidence interval will work quite well for a trimmed normal.

Comment: Tails of dist'n of sample means are uneven because of residual skewness inherited from the truncated dist'n. So in _some_ cases, errors for **two-sided** CIs and tests can cancel out. But 't-ratios' cannot have Student's t distributions and as I said at the top of my Answer, I "wouldn't want to use t methods" for inferences arising from these truncated observations. Maybe bootstrap CIs and permutation tests.